# Cannot find control with name: 'idTypesAccepted'

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-reactive-forms, angular10

I am using a form builder to group form and form array as below

```
this.$form = this.fb.group({
  email: [step2.email || '', [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')]],
  phone: [step2.phone || '', Validators.required],
  configuration: this.fb.group({
    idTypesAccepted: this.fb.array([this.fb.group({
      passport: ['', [Validators.required]],
      nationalId: ['', [Validators.required]],
      otherId: ['', [Validators.required]]
    })])
  })
});
```

**Html**

```
<form [formGroup]="$form" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" *ngIf="$form" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="mt-3">
                <span>Identification documents required *</span><br>
                <small>ID document types accepted at the location</small>
                <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-3" formArrayName="idTypesAccepted">
                    <div *ngFor="let identity of getIdentityControls(); let i=index">
                        <div class="row mb-2">
                            <span class="col-sm-5">Passport</span>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <ui-switch size="small" [formControlName]="i"></ui-switch>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-2">
                            <span class="col-sm-5">National ID</span>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <ui-switch size="small" [formControlName]="i"></ui-switch>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <span class="col-sm-5">Other ID type</span>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <ui-switch size="small" [formControlName]="i"></ui-switch>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Ts method

```
getIdentityControls(): any {
    const value = (this.$form.get('configuration').get('idTypesAccepted') as FormArray).controls;
    return value;
  }
```

**Exception**

```
zone-evergreen.js:172 Uncaught Error: Cannot find control with name: 'idTypesAccepted'
    at _throwError (forms.js:3357)
    at setUpFormContainer (forms.js:3329)
    at FormGroupDirective.addFormArray (forms.js:7402)
    at FormArrayName.ngOnInit (forms.js:7736)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:31910)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:44367)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:44306)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:45328)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:45271)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TestCenterLocationStep2Component.html:45)
```

**Update 1**

```
<form [formGroup]="$form" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" *ngIf="$form" novalidate>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="mt-3" formGroupName="configuration">
                <span>Identification documents required *</span><br />
                <small>ID document types accepted at the location</small>
                <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-3" formArrayName="idTypesAccepted">
                    <div *ngFor="let identity of $form.get('configuration').get('idTypesAccepted')['controls']; let i=index">
                        <div formGroupName="i">
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-sm-5">Passport</span>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <ui-switch size="small" formControlName="passport"> </ui-switch>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-sm-5">National ID</span>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <ui-switch size="small" formControlName="nationalId"> </ui-switch>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <span class="col-sm-5">Other ID type</span>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <ui-switch size="small" formControlName="otherId"> </ui-switch>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Error**

```
VM35372 polyfills.js:3503 Uncaught Error: Cannot find control with path: 'configuration -> idTypesAccepted -> 0 -> '
    at _throwError (VM35379 vendor.js:94054)
    at setUpControl (VM35379 vendor.js:93878)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (VM35379 vendor.js:97660)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (VM35379 vendor.js:98314)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (VM35379 vendor.js:98237)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (VM35379 vendor.js:78042)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (VM35379 vendor.js:89380)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (VM35379 vendor.js:89319)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (VM35379 vendor.js:90341)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (VM35379 vendor.js:90284)
```

Comment: Error occurs whenever u call `getIdentityControls()` or on render ?

Comment: @hansand The error is on formArrayName="idTypesAccepted", getIdentityControls() method is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your getting this error because you have forgot to wrap your `idTypesAccepted` formArray with your `configuration` formGroup. `formGroupName="configuration"`

I also noticed you have used the index as your formControlName.

I fixed the issue in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/formarraybesthansand-ccsz8q?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<div class="mt-3" formGroupName="configuration"> <!-- fixed line -->
                <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-3" formArrayName="idTypesAccepted"
                    *ngFor="let identity of $form.get('configuration').get('idTypesAccepted')['controls']; let i=index">
                    <div [formGroupName]='i'>
                        <div class="row mb-2">
                            <span class="col-sm-5">Passport</span>
                            <div class="col-sm-5">
                                <input size="small" formControlName="passport"/>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row mb-2">
                                <span class="col-sm-5">National ID</span>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <input size="small" formControlName="nationalId"/>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <span class="col-sm-5">Other ID type</span>
                                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                                        <input size="small" formControlName="otherId"/>
                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer can you also add validation either one should be selected

Comment: I am facing the new errro as  Uncaught Error: Cannot find control with name: 'idTypesAccepted'. Updated the question

Comment: try removing `[]`  from `formControlName`

Comment: can you please add checkbox and validate either one is selected

Comment: i think using a radio button is the best way to validate this.

Comment: However the user can select more than 1 item

Comment: for that i think you need to check that in the submit function. i added a sample code in the stackblitz example.